# Sharing xorg or power configuration between the login/lock screen and my shell

Tags: 18.04, login, suspend, power-management, laptop

I have a recent ThinkPad X1 Extreme with switchable NVidia and Intel graphics.

As a former macOS user, I am used to keeping my machine in clamshell mode while working from my desk — closing the lid and keeping the machine on that way throughout the day.

This works out for the most part with the proper configuration on my user side, except when I lock the screen or end my X session for any reason like restarting the machine.

The login UI insists on appearing on the built-in screen and the machine suspends as the lid is closed.

This means if I lock the screen when going out for lunch, I have to manually open the lid again, login there and then close the lid again after login.

Is there a configuration line I'm missing somewhere?

**== Update ==**

I have managed to do a simple `sudo cp ~/.config/monitors.xml /var/lib/lightdm/.config` to get lightdm to move the login window to the external screen by default.

I have also added `LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes` and `HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=yes` to `logind.conf`.

However, the laptop goes to sleep mode as soon as I log in, so I still have to open it up for a brief moment and the current step is to find a way past that.

**==Update 2==**

Just discovered that the `logind.conf` lines should have the value `no` instead of `yes`. The machine boots now, but it seems like GRUB2 does not support mirroring to two different screens at the same time.

Waking up from sleep mode still seems to be an issue however.